# Getting, Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.\n while working with MERN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, mern

I am getting the following error while working with Stripe payment with MERN stack:-

```
Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.
```

My code for router is as given below

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test..."
);

router.post("/placeorder", async (req, res) => {
  const { token, subTotal, currentUser, cartItems } = req.body;
  try {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: token.email,
      source: token.id,
    });
    const payment = await stripe.charges.create(
      {
        amount: subTotal * 100,
        currency: "inr",
        customer: customer.id,
        receipt_email: token.email,
      },
      {
        idempotencyKey: uuidv4,
      }
    );
    if (payment) {
      res.send("Payment successful");
    } else {
      res.send("Payment failed");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Something went wrong",
      error: error.stack,
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where in your code do you redirect the user to the Stripe payment page (step 2 of the [checkout lifecycle](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works#lifecycle))?

Comment: Your code looks normal. It could just be a network issue. Make sure you can curl to Stripe in the same environment, and configure domain and IP whitelist: https://stripe.com/docs/ips

Comment: I am not getting your point @orakaro. May I get more details?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help. Problem solved, there was typing error that was `idempotencyKey: uuidv4,`  which should be like `idempotencyKey: uuidv4( )`.